# Osmosis tutorial

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I'm trying to extract POI data from openstreetmap. On a lot of forum Osmosis is mentioned. I could find it. But I lack a basic tutorial how to install it and run it. I read the wiki but I could not find any step-by-step tutorial. I always get error messages if I want to use it.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

The OSM wiki has an [osmosis page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) and also several [osmosis usage examples](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Example_Usage).

Please note that there are easier ways to extract POIs and other data from OSM, particularly [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) and the frontend [overpass turbo](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo).

Comment: As I wrote I've read the wiki page but it is still not a step-by-step tutorial. I need maybe a video or screenshots. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is necessary. Instead you could try to *explain* us what you have tried so far, what doesn't work and what error messages you are receiving.

Comment: When you work with osmosis, you also need the list of tags which is available at http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/ . For exemple, if you want to extract all airport elements, you request will looks like : osmosis --rbf planet-latest.osm.pbf \
 --nkv keyValueList="aeroway.runway,aeroway.taxiway,aeroway.hangar,aeroway.aerodrome,aeroway.apron,aeroway.gate,aeroway.helipad,aeroway.terminal" \
 --wkv keyValueList="aeroway.runway,aeroway.taxiway,aeroway.hangar,aeroway.aerodrome,aeroway.apron,aeroway.gate,aeroway.helipad,aeroway.terminal" \
 --wx airport.osm